# How can I disable Yocto PROJECT splash display?

Tags: yocto

[splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEfuB.png)

How can I disable yacto PROJECT splash display ?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Yocto project development manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#qemu-tips-and-tricks):

> **Removing the Splash Screen:** You can remove the splash screen when QEMU is booting by using Alt+left. Removing the splash screen allows you to see what is happening in the background.

Although to stay within SO theme, you can also completely remove splash functionality from the image, for this you should use [`IMAGE_FEATURES` variable](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage-imagefeatures) of your image recipe, most of the default images have "splash" defined there and you need to remove it either directly or via ["_remove" syntax](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#removing-override-style-syntax) in your [`local.conf`](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage-localconf) or [`.bbappend`](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-bbappend-files) in [your layer](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#understanding-and-creating-layers).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was interested to use this on my Nitrogen board and I press `Alt+left` that removed the splash screen and in the background I see a message `Please wait: booting...` and all screen was blank. I was expecting it will show the kernel boot logs on screen just like we see on serial console. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @user12345: that depends on boot parameters like kernel output redirection ([console](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel.html)).

Answer (score -1):

according to yocto documentation, it states to remove the splash pass this to the kernel. The above solution did not work for me.

psplash=false